# Autodetect language of a text in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android

For my app I'd like to, given a text , detect its language (the ISO code and a chance for example). I'd like to know if there is some kind of web service or java library for doing so.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Auto-detecting the natural language of a text is relatively easy using a bigram analysis algorithm. You can either implement it by yourself or simply use some existing library, e.g. [Language-Detection](http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/) project.

Comment: How can I use this library. please let me know . Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Translator has [multiple APIs](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/), including HTTP API - you should be able to use it and its [Detect method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512411.aspx)

Unfortunately Google Translate is not an option.

Comment: It is best option I guess and it is free up to 2M chars. It is so easy to implement on Android as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Translate has an API](http://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=google%20translate%20api)

Comment: The Google Translate v1 API will be shut down by the end of this year, and the v2 API is a paid service.

Answer (score 2):

Google Translate which is deprecated was replaced by [Google Translate v2 API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html), which is now a paid service ($20 / 1M chars). (word on the street is that free service was cancelled because of SEO optimizers used it to set fake sites).