# Detect if a list item is written in a certain language

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an app that fetches data from an open data platform and then shows the received data inside a list view, some data comes written in Hebrew, and the country I live in has serious problems with Israel so I am afraid that it could get me in trouble.

is there a way to detect if a list item is written in Hebrew and then remove that item so that it doesn't display?

Comment: Check if words of the list exist in a Hebrew dictionary? Could have a HashSet with say 10000 Hebrew words, and then just go through the list once and check if any words exist in the set, that's O(n).

Comment: No, just a way to check for Hebrew letters.

Comment: Have a list of hebrew letters as unicode strings then, then compare few words from the list, char by char to the letter list.

Comment: Well, Hebrew characters have [their own Unicode block](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_(Unicode_block)), so you could check if a substantial part of the data is Hebrew.

Comment: And is there a way to check if an array list has a certain value inside it? let's say I made an array and named it "hebrewAlph" that has all Hebrew letters in it, how do I check if my actual array list has any item that has any of hebrewAlph values?

Answer (score 1):

A very straightforward method would be to check all characters if they are Hebrew characters.

Hebrew characters all lie in the Unicode Hebrew block, between U+0590 and U+05FF. You can define a threshold a which you consider the text to be Hebrew.

```
Map<Boolean, Long> map = str.chars()
    .mapToObj(i -> i)
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(t -> isHebrew(t), Collectors.counting()));

long hebrew = map.get(true);
long total = map.get(false) + hebrew;
double ratio = hebrew / (double) total;
System.out.println((100 * ratio) + "%");
```

```
static boolean isHebrew(int c) {
    return (c >= 0x0590 && c <= 0x05FF);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443987/autodetect-language-of-a-text-in-java-android) answer:

Auto-detecting the natural language of a text is relatively easy using a bigram analysis algorithm. You can either implement it by yourself or simply use some existing library, e.g. [Language-Detection](https://code.google.com/archive/p/language-detection/) project